# Efficiently partition graph with a given property

Tags: algorithm, graph, partitioning

I'm analyzing data in a social network, represented as a graph. We have a guarantee that there exists a partition *(V1, V2)* of equal size (plus or minus 1), where either each vertex of *V1* is connected to every vertex of *V2*, or connected to no vertex of *V2*, or no vertex of *V1* is connected to any vertex of *V2*. Furthermore, this property is recursive, i.e. each of the two subgraphs generated by this partition have the property as well.

So far I've used a naive, inefficient "guess-and-check" approach which works in our toy examples, but this will not work for larger data sets. I imagine there is a recursive approach that will work better. Any ideas?

Comment: With _of equal size (plus or minus 1)_ you mean that if the number `n` is even, the partitions are of the same size and their sizes differ by one otherwise?

Comment: This is correct

Comment: If each vertex in V1 is either connected to every vertex in V2 or connected to no vertex in V2, do these same rules apply to V2? For example, would a vertex in V2 either have to be connected to all the vertices in V1 or none at all?